# Out of heap memory when executing <jdbc:initalize-database>

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hsqldb

Context.xml

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" ignore-failures="ALL">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:scrubd.sql"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mydb"/>
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
      depends-on="dataSource"
      name="_sessFac"> 
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>      
    <property name="configLocation" value="hibernate.cfg.xml.incDTD"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.shutdown">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

When I am running my ant target on my unit tests, after spring gets initialized the first time, I get an out of memory error. Yet, when I populate my tables by simply naming my database `import.sql` and letting hibernate handle it, I do not get this out of memory error.

Why does this happen?

Also, it takes Spring about a second longer to load the data in the database than hibernate. Bonus points to anyone that can explain why.

StackTrace (from ant)

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:2694)
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:234)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.toString(StringBuffer.java:561)
at org.apache.tools.ant.util.StringUtils.replace(StringUtils.java:92)
at org.apache.tools.ant.util.DOMElementWriter.encodedata(DOMElementWriter.java:501)
at org.apache.tools.ant.util.DOMElementWriter.write(DOMElementWriter.java:236)
at org.apache.tools.ant.util.DOMElementWriter.write(DOMElementWriter.java:221)
```

And the bean causing it has got to be my session factory, since I wouldn't call `<jdbc:initialize-database/>` a 'bean'.

I want to say based on the stack trace that it is reading the entirety of my sql script into a string, since it is quite large; ~38K lines.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the memory exception or at least the last couple lines of it.  Can you figure out which bean is causing the exception?

Comment: @Gray Your wish is my command.

Comment: which web /application server are you using ?

Comment: How big a file in bytes is the ~38k lines?  They may be loading all into memory although that still should only be a couple of megs. Also, what -Xmx settings are you using? Have you tried to increase it?

Comment: 512m for Xmx and the file is 5.53 mB. And I do not want to increase it because I have read the file into my program before using import.sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just saying screw it, and letting hibernate populate my tables. The fact that I am now reading in a 20mB file when doing my unit tests, and I am still not getting an out of memory error with hibernate makes me think that if you want to populate your tables before doing unit tests on them, don't let spring do it. Live and learn.